# change href tag on runtime with your own url

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I have an anchor tag where href is set to `javascript:void(0).`
Can I write a click event dynamically to change the href.

I don't want to call onclick from a href declaration as follows.

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();"></a>`

I want to use the anchor id selector to call the click event as follows (this is not working).

```
document.getElementById('id').onclick = function () { 
    alert("called");
}
```

Comment: Did you give an id to your anchor tag? Doesn't look like it from the example you provided. Also, refrain from assigning an id called ```id```.

Comment: Where is `myJsFunc` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in below way.

```
  <a href="javascript:replaceCtaLink()">

     var replaceCtaLink = function(){
     var url = "";//add url here
     window.location.href = url;
     };
```